# Points near corner

Tags: qgis, arcgis-10.0, arcgis-desktop, spatial-analyst, geocoding

I have a road network (lines) and some POIs (points). These POIs have the information of street name on their attribute table. I've found that some street name from the POI doesn't match with my road network street names. It's something like 12k of POIs that doesn't match. Because some of them are on the corner of streets.

So, **I want to select these POIs**, but I don't know how to do that, can somebody help me?
I'm using ArcGIS 10.0, but I can use QGIS if needed.

This image is what I got, the yellow dots in the corner is what I need to select:

[image: example]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a whatever GIS environment, firstly I would execute a **spatial join** between the POIs and the road network in order to append the road names to the POIs layer according to a specific spatial relationship (nearest). So, we can easily compare the POIs road names with the network ones. For instance, we can add a "flag" field (boolean or integer) in the associated alphanumeric table and fill it with proper value (e.g. 1 if the street names match, 0 otherwise). Finally, we can select the anomalies filtering data using the "flag" values. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

Just do a vlookup (http://spreadsheets.about.com/od/excelfunctions/ss/vlookup.htm) of your data in Excel. The rows that cannot be matched by their streetname will be your corners. Then simply bring this data back into your GIS environment and your POIs will be marked. Alternatively you could bring them back into GIS as a new layer.